# how to store last user input as in a variable?

Tags: autohotkey

My current code read 2 digit input from user  from 10 to 56

is there a way I can save last user input into variable so I can user it later somewhere in code ?

here is same of my code

if user enter 11, I want to save 11 in tht variable so I can user it later
if user enter 21 I want it to store 21 in that variable

```
1::
Input Key, L1


if Key=1
            {
             ; do code
}
if Key=2
            {
             ; do code
}
return

2::
Input Key, L1


if Key=1
            {
             ; do code
}
if Key=2
            {
             ; do code
}
return
```

**edited code**

```
myVar=0

#o::
MsgBox %myVar% - 1 

return
```

so if user entered 11 it will set myVar = 11. 
then I try to subtrace myVar - 1 and try to print in MsgBox but it doesn't ? 
it shows me 11 - 1 instead of 11 subtract 1 
I will use Send, %myVar% - 1 later intead of MsgBox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing  you require the combination of the keys pressed, if 1 was pressed then 2 to do stuff you want to get 12, etc..


just use a global variable

```
global myVar
```

-> a variable define like this is accessible anywhere in the program.

Then just define myVar in you series of If sentences.

```
1::
    Input Key, L1


    if Key=1
    {
        myVar:=11
        ; do code
    }
return
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for awesome idea, so please my edited part of code. it doesn't actually subtract myVar - 1 when I try to MsgBox it.

Comment: Use myVar:= myVar - 1, then print it with msgbox.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of assignment statements in autohotkey: `=` & `:=`

1. `line1 = %g_number% - 1 ;this is a string`
2. `line2 := g_number - 1 ;this is an expression`

if `g_number = 5`

`line1` will evaluate to `5 - 1` and `line2` will evaulate to `4`.

## full code

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

g_number = 0

keys := "0123456789"

Loop, parse, keys
{
    Hotkey, %A_LoopField%, NumberKeyAction
}

return

#o::
    line1 = %g_number% - 1
    line2 := g_number - 1
    msgbox, %line1%`n%line2%
    return

NumberKeyAction:
    Input second_key, L1
    number = %A_ThisHotkey%%second_key%
    tooltip, %number%
    g_number := number
    return
```